# C# Return a private type in protected function where private type will be accessible to all child classes

Tags: c#

I have two classes, `BaseO` and `PrivateO`, defined in another class, `Overflow`. `BaseO` is a public class, and `PrivateO` is private. I also have a child class to `BaseO`, called `ChildO`, which is also public.

Now, in `BaseO`, I want to define a protected function `protected Private0 getPrivate();`, which `ChildO1` can access. But this is not allowed, because `getPrivate` has a different accessibility than `PrivateO`.

I understand why this is a problem, if someone were to inherit `BaseO` from outside `Overflow` they would need to have access to `PrivateO`, which they don't.

I've gotten around the problem for now by using objects and casts, but I'd like to do it more correctly. Is there a way to specify that `BaseO` is not intended to be inherited from outside of `Overflow`?

`internal` is an idea, but I'd like this to work even when the code is not in a different assembly.

I have access to .NET 4.5 and C# 5, but any newer versions would also be interesting.

Example code:

```
public static class Overflow
{
    private class PrivateO
    {
        public int foo;
    }

    public class BaseO
    {
        protected PrivateO GetPrivate() // inconsistent accessibility
        {
            return new PrivateO();
        }
    }

    public class ChildO : BaseO
    {
        private int foo;
        public ChildO()
        {
            this.foo = GetPrivate().foo; // <- desired behavior
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Note that the example code is just that, an example. The real PrivateO class is a whole lot more complex, so it's not just a matter of retrieving an int. It also returns private builder classes and other non-trivial data structures.

**Edit 2:** Changed `Overflow` to a static class to emphasize that it in this case is used more as a namespace than as an instantiable class.

Comment: Is a `Base0` instance ever used outside of `Overflow` or will it always be a `Child0` runtime object?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an accessor property for the private/protected property:

```
class Overflow
{
    private class PrivateO
    {
        public int foo;
    }

    public class BaseO
    {       
        PrivateO privateO = new PrivateO();
        public int PrivateFoo => privateO.foo;
    }

    public class ChildO : BaseO
    {
        private int foo;
        public ChildO()
        {
            this.foo = PrivateFoo;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: This requires me to wrap all functionality I want to use from PrivateO in BaseO though, right?

Comment: Yup. Think of the interface as more of a dto.

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately the real PrivateO class is pretty complex and also returns further private classes. The example code is a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

If `Base0` never needs to be instantiated from the outside and all runtime types will be dervided ones like `Child0` you can restrict inheritance to nested types:

```
public class BaseO
{   
    //private ctor avoids anyone extending this class
    //outside Base0 
    private Base0 { }   
    PrivateO privateO = new PrivateO();
    public int PrivateFoo => privateO.foo;

    public class ChildO : BaseO
    {
        private int foo;
        public ChildO()
        {
            this.foo = PrivateFoo;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
var child0 = new Overflow.Base0.Child0();
```

But you can't do neither of the following outside `Overflow`:

```
class anotherChild0: Overflow.Base0 { }
var base0 = new Overflow.Base0(); //potentially problematic
```

If you actually need to allow `var base0 = new Overflow.Base0();` outside `Overflow` then you are out of luck, you can't have it both ways; if someone can new up a `Base0` and its not sealed, then he will be able to inherit from it.

In this case your best options are:

1. Live with allowing inheritance only inside the same assembly (`internal` constructor)
2. Do not expose `Base0` and `Child0` outside `Overflow`, expose an interface `IBase0`
3. Do a runtime check and zap any class calling `Base0()` from outside the assembly. YUCK! (I don't know why I'm even suggesting this).

Answer (score -1):

You could make the class protected and embed it in BaseO:

```
class Overflow
{


    public class BaseO
    {
        protected class PrivateO
        {
            public int foo;
        }

        protected PrivateO GetPrivate() 
        {
            return new PrivateO();
        }
    }

    public class ChildO : BaseO
    {
        private int foo;
        public ChildO()
        {
            this.foo = GetPrivate().foo; // <- desired behavior
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, PrivateO is used in many other contexts and need to exist in the Overflow class.

Comment: Then you'll either have to make it an internal class if it is only used within the one assembly or make it public. If a class is used in multiple contexts, making it private doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is used in multiple contexts within the Overflow class, not outside of it. I'm basically just looking for a way to avoid having to rewrite the same code over and over for all of BaseO's child classes by putting the PrivateO-related code in the base.

Comment: I think you are still going to have to make it at least internal since BaseO does not inherit from 'Overflow'.

Comment: Why does it matter if `BaseO` does not inherit from `Overflow`? Even if it did it would still have the same accessibility issues.

Comment: It matters in that you could make PrivateO protected then and it's child classes could see it.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to specify that BaseO is not intended to be inherited
>   from outside of Overflow?

I think that's what ['Sealed'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) is for.

> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes
>   from inheriting from it.

Comment: "sealed" prevents inheritance of any kind, unless I misunderstand it?

Comment: Yes, it'll also stop you inheriting from it inside your project. Assuming you need to do that, how about returning a new Sealed class that inherits from BaseO?

Comment: `Sealed` is not an access modifier, it is irrelevant to the question asked